# Kendo Grid - Transport read not getting search criteria from input box

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have your basic Kendo grid, and a text input box. I simply want to pass what's in the box to the transport read after the #searchButton is clicked. This is how I do it. The alert shows me that the value is there, but it is not picked up in "id" in the read of the grid. What am I doing wrong?

```
$("#searchButton").on("click", function () {
    alert($("#searchCriteria").val());
    $($asGrid).data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
});

var asGridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "/api/securitiesapi",
            data: {
                id: $("#searchCriteria").val() 
            }
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "ID",
            fields: {
                CUSIP: { editable: false },
                SecurityType: { editable: false },
                PoolNumber: { editable: false },
                PoolPrefix: { editable: false },
                IssueDate: { editable: false },
                MaturityDate: { editable: false },
                OriginalBalance: { editable: false },
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This is taken straight from the Kendo doc page for the grid:

```
read: {
  url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/twitter/search",
  dataType: "jsonp", // "jsonp" is required for cross-domain requests; use "json" for same-domain requests
  data: {
    q: $("#search").val() // send the value of the #search input to the remote service
  }
}
```

I am doing essentially the same thing, but it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their documentation is either wrong or misleading. To get it to work the way you intend, you should change your data property to a function, as follows:

```
transport: {
  read: {
    url: "/api/securitiesapi",
    data: function() {
      return { id: $("#searchCriteria").val() };
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As I am using the free Kendo, I can't really complain, but as usual the documentation took me almost all the way there, but failed me in the end. :( But this worked, so thanks.